# How to create and send emails from Access database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query that generates a table like this:

Row 1 - ID 1 Peter Parker Task 1 $50

Row 2 - ID 1 Peter Parker Task 2 $55

Row 3 - ID 1 Peter Parker Task 3 $60

Row 4 - ID 2 Mary Jane Task 1 $45

Row 5...

I want to be able to send one email to each person with a list of the tasks and amounts, and the total amount:

Peter Parker

Task 1  $50

Task 2  $55

Task 3  $60

Total   $165

I've got a module that sends email, but it requires a single recipient per row. I'm thinking I need another loop, but I'm lost as how to do this.

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
        Sub SendMessages(Optional AttachmentPath)

      Dim MyDB As Database
      Dim MyRS As Recordset
      Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
      Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
      Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
      Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachments
      Dim TheAddress As String

      Set MyDB = CurrentDb
      Set MyRS = MyDB.OpenRecordset("qry_TeacherPayment - Round 2")
      MyRS.MoveFirst

      ' Create the Outlook session.
      Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

      Do Until MyRS.EOF

       'Set loop variables

     Dim currentRecord As Integer
     Dim oldRecord As Integer
     Dim totalAmt As Double
     currentRecord = MyRS![ID]
     totalAmt = 0

      If (currentRecord = MyRS![ID]) Then

      ' Create the e-mail message.
      Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      oldRecord = currentRecord
      TheAddress = MyRS![WorkEmail]


         With objOutlookMsg
            ' Add the To recipients to the e-mail message.
            Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("TheAddress")
            objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo



            ' Set the from address.
            objOutlookMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "email"

            ' Set the Subject, the Body, and the Importance of the e-mail message.
            .Subject = "Subject"

            objOutlookMsg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

body text

            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "</table></body></html>"

            .Importance = olImportanceNormal 'Normal importance


            ' Resolve the name of each Recipient.
            For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
               objOutlookRecip.Resolve
               If Not objOutlookRecip.Resolve Then
                 objOutlookMsg.Display
               End If
            Next
            .Send
          End With
          End If
          MyRS.MoveNext
       Loop
       Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
       Set objOutlook = Nothing
       DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End Sub
```

Comment: It would be useful to atleast show the code you have so far. This way people can give you idea's or tips on what to do

Comment: Thanks DragonSamu. I've edited my post with the code I've been using for single recipient per row. I was trying to add a loop in the body of the email but kept getting an error 3021 "No current record".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MyRS is returning fields something like PersonID, TaskID, TaskAmt, you need to loop through MyRS and add the Task and Amt to a string variable (eg 'strBody') UNTIL the PersonID changes - at which point you prepare and send the email using objOutlookMsg.

```
Set MyRS = ...
LastPersonID=MyRS!PersonID
Do Until MyRS.EOF
    If MyRS!PersonID=LastPersonID Then
        ' concatenate to strBody
        strBody = strBody & TaskID & "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & TaskAmt

        ' add Amt to Person's Total
        decTotal = decTotal + nz(TaskAmt,0)
    Else
        ' add the Total 
        strBody = strBody & "Total:&nbsp;&nbsp;" & decTotal 

        ' send email using another function, or GoTo a named line, 
        ' using LastPersonID and strBody  
        GoTo send_email

        ' reset the variables
        strBody = ""
        decTotal = 0

        ' concatenate to strBody
        strBody = strBody & TaskID & "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & TaskAmt & "<br/>"
        ' add Amt to Person's Total
        decTotal = decTotal + nz(TaskAmt,0)
    End If

    MyRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks maxhugen, that was a huge help! I found that I had to call the send email function again after the loop to make sure the last record was included in the last email. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final code that works a treat. A huge thanks to maxhugen for putting me on the right path!!

Cheers!

Jason

```
Sub SendNewPaymentEmail(Optional AttachmentPath)

      Dim MyDB As Database
      Dim MyRS As Recordset
      Dim LastTeacherID As Integer
      Dim EmailBody As String
      Dim TotalAmount As Double
      Dim TheAddress As String
      Dim TeacherFirstName As String
      Dim FinalTeacherID As Integer

      Set MyDB = CurrentDb
      Set MyRS = MyDB.OpenRecordset("qry_TeacherPayment - Round 2")
      MyRS.MoveFirst

      LastTeacherID = MyRS![ID]

      Do Until MyRS.EOF

        If MyRS![ID] = LastTeacherID Then

            TheAddress = MyRS![WorkEmail]
            TeacherFirstName = MyRS![FirstName]
            FinalTeacherID = MyRS![TeacherID]
            EmailBody = EmailBody & "<tr><td>" & MyRS![Subject] & " Year " & MyRS![Year] & "</td><td>" & MyRS![TaskName] & "</td><td>$" & MyRS![Teacher Payment] & "</td></tr>"
            TotalAmount = TotalAmount + Nz(MyRS![Teacher Payment], 0)

            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunSQL "Update [tbl_Judging Standards Project round 2] SET [PaymentEmailSent] = -1 WHERE [TeacherID] = " & MyRS![ID] & " AND [TaskIDTRIM] LIKE '" & MyRS![TaskIDTRIM] & "'"
            DoCmd.RunSQL "Update [tbl_Judging Standards Project round 2] SET [PaymentEmailSentDate] = Now() WHERE [TeacherID] = " & MyRS![ID] & " AND [TaskIDTRIM] LIKE '" & MyRS![TaskIDTRIM] & "'"
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        Else

            Call CreateEmail(EmailBody, TotalAmount, TeacherFirstName)

            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [tbl_Payments]([TeacherID],[PaymentType],[Amount],[Description],[PaymentFormSent],[PaymentFormSentDate]) VALUES(" & FinalTeacherID & ", 'Individual Payment'," & TotalAmount & ",'Judging Standards Project Phases 2 and 3 - Payment for work samples - Round 2', -1, NOW())"
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True

            'reset variables
            EmailBody = ""
            TotalAmount = 0


            'start again
            TheAddress = MyRS![WorkEmail]
            TeacherFirstName = MyRS![FirstName]
            LastTeacherID = MyRS![ID]
            FinalTeacherID = MyRS![TeacherID]
            EmailBody = EmailBody & "<tr><td>" & MyRS![Subject] & " Year " & MyRS![Year] & "</td><td>" & MyRS![TaskName] & "</td><td>$" & MyRS![Teacher Payment] & "</td></tr>"
            TotalAmount = TotalAmount + Nz(MyRS![Teacher Payment], 0)

            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunSQL "Update [tbl_Judging Standards Project round 2] SET [PaymentEmailSent] = -1 WHERE [TeacherID] = " & MyRS![ID] & " AND [TaskIDTRIM] LIKE '" & MyRS![TaskIDTRIM] & "'"
            DoCmd.RunSQL "Update [tbl_Judging Standards Project round 2] SET [PaymentEmailSentDate] = Now() WHERE [TeacherID] = " & MyRS![ID] & " AND [TaskIDTRIM] LIKE '" & MyRS![TaskIDTRIM] & "'"
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        End If

        MyRS.MoveNext

        If (MyRS.EOF) Then

        Call CreateEmail(EmailBody, TotalAmount, TeacherFirstName)

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [tbl_Payments]([TeacherID],[PaymentType],[Amount],[Description],[PaymentFormSent],[PaymentFormSentDate]) VALUES(" & FinalTeacherID & ", 'Individual Payment'," & TotalAmount & ",'Judging Standards Project Phases 2 and 3 - Payment for work samples - Round 2', -1, NOW())"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        End If

     Loop

End Sub
```